# Как вывести двойные кавычки в twig?

Tags: php, twig

Как вывести двойные кавычки в twig

```
$str = ' бла бла бла "Такие" дела ';
```

сюда

```
<input type="hidden" value={{str}} >
```

Answer (score 1):

Также, как и любые другие:

```
<input type="hidden" value="{{str}}">
```

Answer (score -1):

Сделайте вывод с фильтром `raw` для отмены экранирования

```
{{str|raw}}
```